# pebble-clay says my project is outdated, but it's not

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I just updated the sdk to 4.1.4 and trying to install clay from command line I get the following message:

```
This projected is outdated (try 'pebble convert-project' or'pebble sdk install 2.9')
```

Now, I am not going to install the 2.9 sdk, of course, and I know that convert is just going to change appinfo.json into pakage.json, which I don't need to do because I am already on sdk 4.1.4.

Has anybody here had the same issue, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pebble-Clay is a JS package that can also be installed by running

```
npm install pebble-clay
```

This fixes the issue.

Alternatively downloading and installing the SDK 2.9 will fix it. (This will not overwrite the latest version of the SDK.)